# window.open not re-using already open window with the same name

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<button class="button" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com','myWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=500,height=500'); return false;">Google</button>
<br /><br />
<button class="button" onclick="window.open('https://www.stackoverflow.com','myWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=500,height=500'); return false;">Stackoverflow</button>
<br /><br />
<a href="https://www.google.com" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com','myWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=500,height=500'); return false;">Google</a>
<br /><br />
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" onclick="window.open('https://www.stackoverflow.com','myWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=500,height=500'); return false;">Stackoverflow</a>
```

All 4 of these links have the same name (myWindow), I'm expecting to click the first button and a new window to open, then when I click the second button it will overwrite the window that was previously opened with the new link.  But that's not happening, instead it's opening a second window.

Both the `button` tag and the `a href` do the same thing where they are opening new windows instead of re-using a previously opened window with one of the buttons or links.  Even clicking the same button or link results in a new window opening.  If I start clicking all of the buttons and links it will sometimes re-use one of the windows (the intended behavior) but I can't figure out why, it seems random.

I've tried this is Chrome, Edge, and Firefox with the same result.

How do I make it re-use an already opened window?

Comment: This is something specific to Google. It doesn't allow being opened in a popup window, and when that error happens the window doesn't get reused. Replace `www.google.com` with a different site and this works.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/e0L8savy/7/ for an example with Yahoo insetad of Google.

Comment: @Barmar how can a website block such behaviour?

Comment: It sends this header: `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy:
same-origin-allow-popups; report-to="gws"`